# Как добавить элемент в меню?

Tags: wordpress

Предположим, я хочу в элемент `<li>`, созданного мной посредством функции `wp_nav_menu()` в WordPress, добавить элемент `<i>`. Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

для этого есть несколько вариантов:

- использовать параметр `link_before` из функции [wp_nav_menu](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu#link_before)
- использовать фильтр [nav_menu_item_title](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_item_title)
- использовать параметр `walker` из функции [wp_nav_menu](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu#walker) через который вы можете переопределить класс для построения более специфичного макета [walker_nav_menu](https://wp-kama.ru/function/walker_nav_menu)

Comment: Немного неточно сформулировал. Мне на самом деле нужно добавить элемент в <a>, который находится в li. Перечисленные Вами методы насколько я понял не дают конкретно этой возможности.

Comment: я советую вам более подробно ознакомится с предложенными вариантами и посмотреть как формируются пункты меню. по ссылке класс через который формируется меню https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php